# Debugging a Qt + Photoshop plugin crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, crash, photoshop

I'm trying to implement a Qt window within a Photoshop plugin. I created a window with Qt Creator then exported it inside Visual Studio Express 2010. I've managed to get everything to compile.

The only problem is that Photoshop crashes when I try to open the window. How can I debug this error?

I am using Qt 5.1 32-bit and the latest Photoshop SDK.

Comment: MSVC Menu - Debug - Attach to process... Ofc you should compile plugin with debug information.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't see the 'attach to process' in the debug menu. i use VC2010 Express is that the reason?

Comment: Yes, it is - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c6wf8e4z(v=vs.100).aspx